# New to Linux, trying to install FFmpeg but missing dependencies from LibaV

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, libav, elementaryos

Currently using ElementaryOS distro, just got into development on linux and still confused on many things. I'm trying to install FFmpeg for a project I'm working on, when installing the .deb I get this error message https://pastebin.com/eivHN9sy . I somewhat understand what the message is saying, I'm missing several components the LibaV library has, but I'm confused on how to install these components. I guess that sorta summarizes my experience with Linux so far, how on Earth do I install things. Would appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction for this one as I'm a little lost on how to do simple things.

Comment: try googling how install libavcodec.  ElementaryOS is based on Ubuntu which is based on Debian, and people typically use `apt` package manager.with debian

Comment: i'm no linux expert but you could try the apt commands mentioned  https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libavcodec-dev  `sudo apt-get update -y` and `sudo apt-get install -y libavcodec-dev` Good chance that will work

Comment: and if you think linux is awkward, ffmpeg is a whole new level of awkwardness that has a lot of the awkwardness of linux.

Comment: @barlop I appreciate the help, glad to hear its only downhill from here :). I actually ran into that exact same tutorial you mentioned before posting the question and the issue still occurs. I have tried re-running the commands and rebooting and each time it says the package is already installed. I did this command for all the required dependencies and not a single one has disappeared from the error list.

Comment: well you should have included that in your question

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of details. Please include infos on what exact .deb file you tried, what commands you ran, what the error output was, etc. Otherwise we cannot really help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not sure if it was the solution I was hoping for but it seems using snap to install ffmpeg appears to do so successfully without any dependency issues.